# Strange unit version error - Is DUnitX depending on DUnit or the other way around?

Tags: dunit, dunitx

I was using Delphi xe4 to compile https://github.com/hprose/hprose-delphi/blob/master/Test/HproseTest.dpr

And got the following error which I spent tens of minutes and still couldn't figure out why.

I've **tried deleting** all 'DUnitX*.dcu" and compile again, with no luck.

What puzzled me is that, why the unit TextTestRunner from **DUnit** (born first) relies on a unit from **DUnitX** which was born later?

Any hint? Thanks.

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] HproseTest.dpr(37): F2051 Unit TextTestRunner was compiled with a different version of DUnitX.TestFramework.ITestListener
```

And here is the screenshot I made for making the problem description clear:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the repository and it was compiling on the first try but i only have Delph XE8. But i found out that there is a unit called TestFramework.pas in DUnit and DUnitX. While TextTestRunner relies on DUnit, it can only find DUnitX's unit. So, I think you should check your Delphi librarypath.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MxNbrt. The one I found in the DUnitX folder is `DUnitX.TestFramework.pas` (note the `DUnitX.` prefix), so I guess it's not the same?

Comment: I compared them and they have literally nothing in common. So you definitly need the Testframework.pas of DUnit

Comment: Delphi often adds DUnitX to its unit scope names. That is why it then finds `TestFramework` in a uses in the file `DUnitX.TestFramework.pas`